# MySQL Query Not giving expected Result != not working

Tags: mysql, database

I have following query, but it is not giving result. There are two tables, visitSearchEngine and clubUsers. I want to list the users which are not in clubUsers. But using !=  is not helping me out. It shows me the users which are present in clubUsers table too.

```
 SELECT distinct(vs.users), vs.avisitedDate FROM visitSearchEngine vs, clubUsers cu  
 WHERE vs.users!=''
 AND (vs.users!=cu.users)
 AND vs.status='0' AND vs.hitType='googleIdentified'
 AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)>=5
 AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)<5
```

Please advise where I am getting wrong and suggest if there is another good way of writing this query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(vs.users), vs.avisitedDate FROM visitSearchEngine vs, 
WHERE vs.users!='' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clubUsers cu  WHERE vs.users = cu.users )
AND vs.status='0' AND vs.hitType='googleIdentified'
AND ((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)>=5
AND ((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)<5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT distinct(vs.users), vs.avisitedDate
 FROM visitSearchEngine as vs LEFT JOIN clubUsers as cu ON vs.users= cu.users
 WHERE vs.status='0' AND vs.hitType='googleIdentified'
 AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)>=5
 AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),vs.avisitedDate)))/60)<5
 AND cu.users IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `IS NOT NULL` operator:

```
vs.users IS NOT NULL
```

You cannot compare against `NULL` with string operators:

```
mysql> SELECT NULL='', NULL<>'';
+---------+----------+
| NULL='' | NULL<>'' |
+---------+----------+
|    NULL |     NULL |
+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'd also suggest make your query easier to read by:

1. Removing redundant parenthesis
2. Using explicit `JOIN`s